# 14.04 installer, how to fix screen before booting it?

Tags: laptop

so, the installer boots up, until I can hear that ubuntu drum sound, so it is working, but the screen is completely messed, the mouse wont show up, and only several vertical colored lines cover up the screen and they are static...

I think I must, in someway, force the screen to some setup right?

Comment: I did not have a "black scren" but I will try this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try booting with nomodeset in the kernal options - this prevents the graphics driver from starting until the xOrg drivers are loaded, and may solve your issues.  This is a temporary procedure (it does not make a permanent change)

At boot time, hold down the right shift key so that the grub boot menu appears.

Press 'e' to edit the Ubuntu boot entry

Use your cursor keys to move to the line that ends with "quiet splash"

Change the "quiet splash" to read "quiet splash nomodeset"

press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to boot using the temporary parameters.

If this resolves your issue, you should modify your grub files to match this setup.  The easiest way to do this would be to install [grub-customizer](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1664134)

Comment: I selected `nomodeset` as shown on the "black screen" question, on 14.04, I hit shift key but a graphic menu appeared and the boot options were promptly available too to we type at; the nomodeset did not appear in the line but it was used as I selected it!

Comment: @AquariusPower - been out on a camping trip with my son - are you still having a problem?  Ca you describe your hardware (system type, graphics card, etc)

Comment: cool! :), I was able to boot and prepare the system for installing, I think your answer is correct (despite I could not follow the exact steps on ubuntu 14.04, I will try again, I only got a graphical menu to choose "nomodeset"), I will just finish installation and make the changes to grub, so I can confirm it all :)

Comment: @AquariusPower  Good Luck!

Comment: to boot the installation pendrive, nomodeset worked; but it was also used to configure grub on the installed system and all the fade effects were utterly slow, so I had to remove nomodeset and now everything is fast again :)

Comment: So, it sounds as though you are up and running?  There are some other variants of the nomodeset, which determine when in the boot process the graphics become live.

Comment: despite I believe an updated release of ubuntu live cd may work, because I only tested without nomodeset after fully upgrading the system :)